# wkhtmltopdf giving error inside the docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am getting the following error inside my docker container:

[image: Getting this error inside the docker container when I run the wkhtmltopdf command]

How can I update my dockerfile, so that while building the container it builds with a version of wkhtmltopdf with patched Qt.

Following is my dockerfile:

```
...
RUN apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the following dependencies with wkhtmltopdf worked out for me:

```
...
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y openssl build-essential xorg libssl1.0-dev
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
RUN tar xvJf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
RUN cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmlto* /usr/bin/
...
```

Comment: I have maybe a similar issue.  Moved to Docker with composer package and using wkhtmltopdf in the container.  I am using this wrapper:  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy  and the container binary at /usr/bin.  All still working, but the pagination feature (i.e. adding the footer) does not work and some config options are not supported.  Do I just need to build in the DockerFile as outlines above ?

Comment: This is from my existing DockerFile:
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    dcmtk \
    wkhtmltopdf \
    nginx \
    supervisor

Comment: Sweet, that seems to have worked.  Attaching my DockerFile for the build of the nginx php-fpm container that is part of my larger project.  Running a Laravel app from there.

Comment: I got an error using libssl1.0-dev, so I changed to libssl1.1 .  Not sure if that has to be -dev or not ?

Comment: Amazing thank you! i've been struggling to make it work

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
# Install dependencies, libssl1.1-dev ?
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    xvfb \
    wget \
    openssl \
    xorg \
    libssl1.1 \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev \
    dcmtk \
    nginx \
    supervisor
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
RUN tar xvJf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
RUN cp wkhtmltox/bin/wkhtmlto* /usr/bin/
# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# adjustments to php.ini base on the production version.

# Install extensions and configure

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd sockets


# RUN sed -E -i -e 's/max_execution_time = 1200/max_execution_time = 120/' /etc/php.ini \
#  && sed -E -i -e 's/memory_limit = 128M/memory_limit = 512M/' /etc/php.ini \
#  && sed -E -i -e 's/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 64M/' /etc/php.ini \
#  && sed -E -i -e 's/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 64M/' /etc/php.ini

# php artisan storage:link 
# THAT NEEDS TO BE RUN FROM THE nginx-home/LaravelPortal/ directory to symlink the storage directory.  NEED to figure out how to do that.
# sudo docker exec -it  orthanc-docker-dev_ris_php-fpm_1 /bin/bash
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Added this as an answer that works for my build.  Now all options seem to be available.